# Hypothesis testing: mean comparison

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I had great difficulties with an exam question and was wondering if any of you could help me understand it.

I was requested to do the following test at 5% level

$\left\{\begin{matrix}H_{0}:\mu _{1}=\mu _{2}
\\ H_{1}:\mu _{1}\neq\mu _{2}
\end{matrix}\right.$

I had the following data:

$\begin{matrix}
n_{1}=11 & \bar{X_{1}}=7.25 & S_{1}^{2}=1.5\\
n_{2}=9 & \bar{X_{2}}=6.62 & S_{2}^{2}=1.2
\end{matrix}$

I guess I had to compute the following test statistic:

$T(\underline{X})=\frac{\bar{X_{1}}-\bar{X_{2}}-c}{\sqrt{\frac{n_{1}S_{1}^{2}+n_{2}S_{2}^{2}}{n_{1}+n_{2}-2}\frac{n_{1}+n_{2}}{n_{1}n_{2}}}}$

Where $c=0$  and $T(\underline{X})\sim t_{n_{1}+n_{2}-2}$

However, I was only given the standard normal distribution table and the Fisher distribution table.

I know that

$t_{n-1}:=\tfrac{N(0,1)}{\sqrt{\frac{\chi _{n-1}^{2}}{n-1}}}$

So I guess that (unsure):

$t_{n_{1}+n_{2}-2}:=\tfrac{N(0,1)}{\sqrt{\frac{\chi _{n_{1}+n_{2}-2}^{2}}{n_{1}+n_{2}-2}}}$

However, I don't have the $\chi^{2}$ distribution table. How can I still come up with a sensible answer?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

From the very sketchy description, it seems that this is a 2-sample t-test.
I will do the 'pooled' version of this test, which assumes population
variances are equal. That seems the closest match to the formula you give in your question. Output from Minitab 17 follows:

```
Sample   N  Mean  StDev  SE Mean
1       11  7.25   1.23     0.37
2        9  6.22   1.10     0.36

Difference = μ (1) - μ (2)
Estimate for difference:  1.030
95% CI for difference:  (-0.074, 2.134)
T-Test of difference = 0 (vs ≠): 
    T-Value = 1.96  P-Value = 0.066  DF = 18
Both use Pooled StDev = 1.1690
```

The pooled SD is $S_p = \sqrt{\frac{(n_1 - 1)S_1^2 + (n_2 - 1)S_2^2}{n_1 + n_2 - 2}} = 1.169.$ Then $T = \frac{\bar X_1 - \bar X_2}{S_p\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}}}.$

I cannot account for the absence of a t table with your exam.
Without such a table, two reasonable approaches are possible:

**(i)** The t statistic is $T = 1.96.$ For $n_1 + n_2 - 2 = 18$ degrees
of freedom the t statistic is 'close' to standard normal but not
exactly. If it were normal, the critical value would be to reject
at the 5% level, if $|T| > 1.96.$ Your t value happens to be
exactly 1.96. The critical value for $\mathsf{T}(18)$ has to be larger
than 1.96. (All t distributions have heavier tails than standard normal.)

So you can guess that
the sample means are *not* significantly different. (The exact 5% critical
value for $\mathsf{T}(18)$ is $2.10,$ which confirms the statement above.)
From R statistical software:

```
 qt(.975,18)
 ## 2.100922
```

**(ii)** You say you have a table of the F-distribution. You could use
the fact that $T^2 \sim \mathsf{F}(1,18).$ From the F-table, you can 
see that he 5% critical value for $T^2$ is $4.41.$ Therefore, you cannot
reject at the 5% level (no guessing involved) because $T^2 = 3.84 < 4.41.$
Notice that (using either t table or F table) the P-value is $P(|T| > 1.96) = P(T^2 > 3.84) = 0.066 > .05.$

```
qf(.95, 1, 18)
## 4.413873

2*pt(-1.96, 18)
## 0.06566396
1-pf(1.96^2, 1, 18)
## 0.06566396
```

The figure below shows PDFs of $\mathsf{T}(18)$ [left] and $\mathsf{F}(1,18)$ with
critical values as vertical red lines and observed values of $T$ and $F$ as
vertical black lines.

[image]